# How do I bind an ObservableCollection of Dictionaries to DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to understand how can I bind an `ObservableCollection<*Dictionary<string, DBRecord>>` to an `ItemSource` property of a `DataGrid`.

Below you can see the classes that represent my db table in memory. I need to do it this way because table schema is described in an standalone .xml file (I can't change it).

```
public abstract class DBField {
    public string Name;

    public DBField(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class DBValueField<T> : DBField {
    public T Value;

    public DBValueField(string name, T value) : base(name) {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class DBTextField : DBValueField<string> {
    public DBTextField(string name, string value) : base(name, value) { }
}

public class DBIntField : DBValueField<int> {
    public DBIntField(string name, int value) : base(name, value)
    {}
}

public class DBFloatField : DBValueField<float> {
    public DBFloatField(string name, float value) : base(name, value)
    {}
}

public class DBDoubleField : DBValueField<double> {
    public DBDoubleField(string name, double value) : base(name, value)
    {}
}

public class DBBoolField : DBValueField<bool> {
    public DBBoolField(string name, bool value) : base(name, value)
    {}
}

public class DBRecord {
    public Dictionary<string, DBField> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class DBTable {
    private readonly XmlSchema schema;
    public List<DBRecord> Records { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Database ViewModel:

```
public class DatabaseViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public Dictionary<string, DBTable> Tables { get; private set; }
    public DBTable ActiveTable { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DBRecord> ActiveData { get; set; }
}
```

I have a **ComboBox** with a full list of all loaded db tables and I have a **DataGrid** element right under that ComboBox. The idea is that when you select a particular table, the ViewModel will populate the DataGrid with columns (retrieved from table schema) and with values (values are assigned to the **ActiveData** as a reference and retrieved from a selected table in a ComboBox).
The problem is that I don't understand how to properly bind such a structure to a DataGrid.

My ideas were:

- Converter that knows how to access data
- Mapping the data to custom-tailored classes per each table (which I really wanna avoid since it's unknown what tables will be required)
- Somehow binding a collection of dictionaries to the DataGrid (trying to do it but can't quite understand how to)
- Somehow manually insert rows in a DataGrid from code-behind?

This is my WPF markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tablesComboBox"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
        Style="{StaticResource DarkFlatComboBox}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tables, Mode=OneWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Key"
        SelectedValuePath="Value"
        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
        Style="{StaticResource DarkDataGrid}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveTable.Records,
                            Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Don't do this. Flatten/deconstruct the dictionary to make it a simple list of data items. Dictionary is not a reasonable data source. It's a special collection to provide very fast lookup. Using it in the UI leads to unnatural and too complex code most of the time (like in your case).

Comment: @BionicCode Gotcha, trying to do exactly that

Comment: @BionicCode I managed to replace Dictionary with a List. So now I bind `List<DBRecord>` that translates into `List<List<DBField>>`. DBField has two properties: Name and Value, where Name is a column name and Value is an actual row value for that column. How do I properly set path for the ItemsSource?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correectly and how a list of lists is supposed to be presented by a DataGrid. Usually you use a list of data items as data source, where each item is presented as a row and each property of this item makes a column. With an auto generated table, each property _name_ makes the columns header and the property value is the presented as cell value. You can manually define the columns to customize column names and/or property mapping and cell layout. So what you want is a `List<DBField>`.

Comment: For this ireason it does not seem to make much sense to get the column header from a property value on the item. I assume that each item has or may have a different value for the property `Name`? The column header must be constant.

Comment: Alternatively create a [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0#examples) from your data models/database result. You can assign/bind it directly to `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.

Comment: @BionicCode DataTable seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I think that I've tried to reinvent the wheel with my Table, Record and Field classes because DataTable does exactly what I tried to do! Thank you very much again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on BionicCode's comment it seems that I tried to reinvent the wheel by creating `DataTable`, `DataColumn`, `DataRow` and other classes.

I removed my classes and based my code around System.Data classes for tables.

Besides, `DataTable` perfectly binds to a `DataGrid` and it solves all my issues.